# Entry widget factory class with a factory method

Tags: python, tkinter, design-patterns, abstract-class, factory-pattern

I have a modified version of Burkhard Meier's Button factory that needs to be extended with a text field factory. I need to follow the below structure:

Expected output:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Menu

class ButtonFactory():
    def createButton(self, type_):
        return buttonTypes[type_]()

class ButtonBase():     
    relief     ='flat'
    foreground ='white'
    def getButtonConfig(self):
        return self.relief, self.foreground

class ButtonRidge(ButtonBase):
    relief     ='ridge'
    foreground ='red'        

class ButtonSunken(ButtonBase):
    relief     ='sunken'
    foreground ='blue'        

   
class ButtonGroove(ButtonBase):
    relief     ='groove'
    foreground ='green'        

buttonTypes = [ButtonRidge, ButtonSunken, ButtonGroove]
```

Is the below a correct extension of the above code to create a concrete Entry widget Factory class with a fFactory method called `generateText(..)`? My instructions say tkinter textfields are `Entry` widgets.

```
class TextFactory():
    def generateText(self):
        sv=tk.StringVar()
        tx = factory.generateText(0).getTextConfig()[0]
        sv.set(tx)
        bg  = factory.generateText(0).getTextConfig()[1]
        action = tk.Entry(self.widgetFactory, textvariable=sv, background=bg, foreground="white")   
        action.grid(column=1, row=1)'''
```

Is there a Python ninja out there that could help me understand how to do the above and also how to:

1. Create an abstract product named `TextBase()` that will have default attributes `textvariable` and `background`?
2. Declare a `getTextConfig(...)` method.
3. Create 3 concrete text products named `text_1`/`2`/`3`/ that will be assigned `textvariable` values ‘type red / type blue / type green” as shown in the image below.
4. Extend the OOP class with `createTextFields()` method that creates a factory object.
5. I’ve been given the below code as well but I don’t know how to implement it to solve the above.

   ```
    #Entry field 1
    sv=tk.StringVar()
    tx = factory.createText(0).getTextConfig()[0]
    sv.set(tx)
    bg  = factory.createText(0).getTextConfig()[1]
    action = tk.Entry(self.widgetFactory, textvariable=sv, background=bg, foreground="white")   
    action.grid(column=1, row=1)
   ```

Comment: This sounds like a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com rather than stackoverflow

Comment: This all sounds overly complex. Is this a homework assignment? The tail end of the question sounds a lot like a homework assignment.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251616/entry-widget-factory-class-with-a-factory-method

Comment: @BryanOakley, Yes and No, it is not my assigment, it is some exercise that I've found and that I want to solve, any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: How do you expect or intend to use this widget factory? I think you need to [edit] your question and provide more code to make it less abstract and more likely someone will answer (and less work for them to do so). I also doubt you get much help on codereview.stackexchange.com the way it currently stands.

Comment: @martineau: I work with children with certain disabilities that want to learn new skills, I am trying to create a coding class for people trying to learn Python,, but before I can teach others I need to grasp the concepts myself. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Dylan: Sorry, am not familiar with Meier's work. I do know a bit about the Factory pattern and don't see why you want to make implement it as a class when a function would work fine — which was part of the reason why I asked about how you intended on using one.